# how can i make a sprite from a spritesheet increase its size?

Tags: java, spritesheet

I want to be able to increase the size of a sprite to give the illusion that it is walking towards you (or decrease in size to move away).
how do i manipulate the size of a loaded sprite off a sprite sheet (png format, if that matters)?

Comment: Typically, you will do it by applying a scaling factor. Think in Doom 1, Doom 2 sprites, scenarios were 3D but enemies were 2D and they scaled with distance to the first person camera. Specify an API so we can answer with an example. For example: canvas, OpenGL, libGDX, etc.

Comment: Duplicates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java may help.